# I am confused seeing this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Where did I do wrong?

```
SELECT constituency,party, votes
FROM    (SELECT constituency,party, votes, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY votes DESC) as posn
        FROM ge WHERE posn =1 and yr  = 2017 )
WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
ORDER BY constituency,votes DESC
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving an alias to your subquery:

```
SELECT s.constituency,s.party, s.votes 
FROM  (
   SELECT constituency,party, votes, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY votes DESC) as posn 
   FROM ge 
   WHERE posn =1 and yr  = 2017 ) s
WHERE s.constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026'
ORDER BY s.constituency,s.votes DESC
```

On a side note, I am not entirely sure if using `between` on a `string` column will give you the desired results, might be better to do this instead:

```
s.constituency in ('S14000021', 'S14000022', 'S14000023', 
                   'S14000024', 'S14000025' 'S14000026')
```

**Edited query**

Looks like you are trying to find out the party that got the highest votes in a constituency, so the query should look something like (`rank` should be calculated per constituency, hence the `partition by`):

```
SELECT s.constituency,s.party, s.votes 
FROM  (
   SELECT constituency,
          party, 
          votes, 
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY constituency ORDER BY votes DESC) posn 
   FROM ge 
   WHERE yr  = 2017 ) s
WHERE s.constituency in ('S14000021', 'S14000022', 'S14000023', 
                   'S14000024', 'S14000025' 'S14000026')
and s.posn = 1
ORDER BY s.constituency,s.votes DESC
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this Error:
Invalid column name 'posn'.

Comment: remove 'as' before posn. just give space. i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your original query wold be written like this:

```
SELECT constituency, party, votes
FROM (SELECT ge.*,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY votes DESC) as posn
      FROM ge
      WHERE constituency BETWEEN 'S14000021' AND 'S14000026' AND
            yr = 2017
     ) ge
WHERE posn = 1 
ORDER BY constituency, votes DESC;
```

This fixes the alias, the use of `pos` in the `where` clause, and puts the filtering in the subquery (not an error but recommended in MySQL).

This returns the constituency or constituencies that have exactly the same maximum votes.

If you want the winner in each constituency, then you want `partition by constituency` in the `rank()`.  That is speculation, however, and not related to why your original query does not compile.